# How to exit phantom if it hangs on page.open (with example)

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

```
 var system = require("system");
      var page;

      // user supplied url
      var myurl = system.args[1];
      // var myurl = 'https://waffles.ch/';

      page = require('webpage').create();

      // suppress errors from output
      page.onError = function(msg, trace) {};

      // 5 seconds
      page.settings.resourceTimeout = 5000;

      // page.settings.javascriptEnabled = false;

      page.open(myurl, function(status) {

          //hack for page.open not hooking into phantom.onError
          setTimeout(function() {
              if (status !== "success") {
                  console.log(myurl);
                  phantom.exit();
                  throw new Error("Unable to access network");
              } else {
                  var pageTitle = myurl.replace(/http.*\/\//g, "").replace("www.", "").split("/")[0];
                  var filePath = "img/" + pageTitle + '.jpg';
                  page.render(filePath, {format: 'jpeg', quality: '75'});
                  console.log(filePath);
                  phantom.exit();
              }

          }, 0);
      });
```

Using the above code to take screenshots works fine for most webpages.
Running the script through the console or a web app with the url "https://waffles.ch/", however, causes it to hang infinitely on page.open (i believe).

The reason for this I assume is because this URL contains some JS animation which doesn't stop running (an aeroplane flying across the screen), and it causes Phantom to lock up. Is this a known bug??

I'm quite sure JS causes the hang because if I switch it off with `page.settings.javascriptEnabled = false;` then the screenshot for the page is rendered without any problems.

I can't realistically switch off javascript to take screenshots for obvious reasons (page.evaluate, redirects etc), so here's my 2 questions.

1.) Is there a way to render a screenshot for a webpage containing animation like `waffles.ch` without having to switch off javascript??

2.) If a webpage does hang, on `page.open` how can I exit phantom and possibly also return an errror??)

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Phantom version: 2.1.1
OS: Windows 7 64 bit.

Other thing I've tried.(but still hangs for above url)

with try/catch

```
var system = require("system");
var page;
// user supplied url
var myurl = system.args[1];

var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open(myurl, function (status) {
    try {
        if (status !== "success") {
            console.log("Unable to access network");
            phantom.exit();
        } else {
            //do some stuff with the DOM
            var pageTitle = myurl.replace(/http.*\/\//g, "").replace("www.", "").split("/")[0];
            var filePath = "img/" + pageTitle + '.jpg';
            page.render(filePath, {format: 'jpeg', quality: '75'});
            console.log(filePath);
            phantom.exit();
        }
    } catch (ex) {
        var fullMessage = "\nJAVASCRIPT EXCEPTION";
        fullMessage += "\nMESSAGE: " + ex.toString();
        for (var p in ex) {
            fullMessage += "\n" + p.toUpperCase() + ": " + ex[p];
        }
        console.log(fullMessage);
    }
});


// ******************************
```

Using `waitfor()` function.
https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/waitfor.js

```
var system = require("system");
var page;
// user supplied url
var myurl = system.args[1];

var page = require('webpage').create();

// suppress errors from output
page.onError = function(msg, trace) {
  console.log("Error occurred" + msg);
  phantom.exit();
};

// 5 seconds
page.settings.resourceTimeout = 5000;

page.open(myurl, function (status) {
    // Check for page load success
    if (status !== "success") {
        console.log("Unable to access network");
        phantom.exit();
    } else {
        waitFor(function() {
            // Check in the page if a specific element is now visible
            return page.evaluate(function() {

                return $("body").is(":visible");
            });
        }, function() {
           console.log("body is visible");
           phantom.exit();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: You could set up a watchdog timer which, if allowed to time out, outputs a tagged message to `console.log`. You can then parse the message in the runner context with an `onConsoleMessage` listener which can issue a `phantom.exit()` statement.

Comment: You have the weirdest use of onError callback I've ever seen - just to ignore errors. One should watch out for errors, not suppress their output.

Comment: @Cool Blue, Thanks never heard of watchdog timers before. Would this script achieve what you suggest?  https://github.com/GCheung55/watchout

Comment: @Vaviloff I agree, you shouldn't suppress output errors, that part of the code was found in another script. Errors are displayed in the last example.

Comment: In your case I would just put something like `setTimeout(function(){console.log('>>>EXIT')}, 5000)` at the start of your `page.open` callback and detect that in the onConsoleMessage listener I suggested.

Comment: @Cool Blue,That's not working, unfortunately.I don't think any script added _inside_ the `page.open` callback will be read, because it jams-up/hangs at `page.open` and goes no further. I need something that will force the script to exit it it hasn't executed `page.open`after a period of time. Or maybe less specific to `page.open`and just time out the script if it hasn't finished after a period of time. Ideally ` page.settings.resourceTimeout = 5000;`, would have dealt with this...

Comment: OK, I did it myself to see if I was lying.  See my answer below ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there is no way to terminate phantom in this situation, at least not by itself but, there is a way to avoid the problem.

The root cause is that the implementation of `requestAnimationFrame` in phantomJs doesn't play nice with tweenJs.  The number returned to the callback by phantom is a UNIX epoch number (but with fractional seconds) and tweenJs expects a  DOMHighResTimeStamp (like what you would get from [performance.now()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now), starting from zero when the process starts).  The epoch number is always much higher than the tween end time, so every update is seen as the end of a tween and this causes `TWEEN.update` to slam through into the next cycle, thus causing it to block.

The way to fix it is to inject a polyfill, including a `performance.now` pollyfil, to overwrite phantom's `requestAnimationFrame` implimentation, using `page.injectJs`.

Here is the code that needs to be injected (or st better)...

*request-animation-frame.js*

```
// Include a performance.now polyfill
var now = (function () {
    // In node.js, use process.hrtime.
    if (this.window === undefined && this.process !== undefined) {
      now = function () {
        var time = process.hrtime();

        // Convert [seconds, microseconds] to milliseconds.
        return time[0] * 1000 + time[1] / 1000;
      };
    }
    // In a browser, use window.performance.now if it is available.
    else if (this.window !== undefined &&
      window.performance !== undefined &&
      window.performance.now !== undefined) {

      // This must be bound, because directly assigning this function
      // leads to an invocation exception in Chrome.
      now = window.performance.now.bind(window.performance);
    }
    // Use Date.now if it is available.
    else if (Date.now !== undefined) {
      now = Date.now;
    }
    // Otherwise, use 'new Date().getTime()'.
    else {
      now = function () {
        return new Date().getTime();
      };
    }
    return now
  })();

// http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/
// http://my.opera.com/emoller/blog/2011/12/20/requestanimationframe-for-smart-er-animating

// requestAnimationFrame polyfill by Erik Möller. fixes from Paul Irish and Tino Zijdel

// MIT license

// Adapted to shim floating point milliseconds since the page was opened
// https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/05/requestAnimationFrame-API-now-with-sub-millisecond-precision?hl=en


(function() {
  var lastTime = 0;
  var rAF = window.requestAnimationFrame;

  window.requestAnimationFrame = function(callback) {
    var currTime = now();
    var timeToCall = Math.max(0, 1000/60 - (currTime - lastTime));
    var tcb = currTime + timeToCall;
    var cbprxy = (function (cb, t) {
      return function (discard) {
        cb(t)
      }
    })(callback, tcb);
    var id = rAF
      ? rAF.call(window, cbprxy)
      : window.setTimeout(function() { callback(tcb); }, timeToCall);

    lastTime = currTime + timeToCall;

    return id;
  };

  if(!window.cancelAnimationFrame)
    window.cancelAnimationFrame = clearTimeout

}());
```

and here is the code to put in phantoms outer context to inject it...

```
page.onInitialized = function() {
  page.injectJs('request-animation-frame.js');
};
```

In the context of your question...

```
/**
 * Adjusted by cool.blue on 08-Sep-16.
 */
var system = require('system');
var page;

// user supplied url
var myurl = system.args[1] || 'https://waffles.ch/';

page = require('webpage').create();

// suppress errors from output
page.onError = function(msg, trace) {};

function exitPhantom (message) {
  console.log(message)
  phantom.exit(message.match("Error:") ? 1 : 0)
}

page.onConsoleMessage = function(message) {
  system.stdout.write('> ' + message + '\n')
};

page.onInitialized = function() {
  page.injectJs('request-animation-frame.js');
};

// 5 seconds
page.settings.resourceTimeout = 10000;

// page.settings.javascriptEnabled = false;
page.open(myurl, function(status) {

  //hack for page.open not hooking into phantom.onError
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (status !== "success") {
      exitPhantom('Error: ' + status);
      throw new Error("Unable to access network");
    } else {
      var pageTitle = myurl.replace(/http.*\/\//g, "").replace("www.", "").split("/")[0];
      var filePath = "img/" + pageTitle + '.jpg';
      page.render(filePath, {format: 'jpeg', quality: '75'});
      console.log(filePath);
      exitPhantom(status);
    }
  }, 1000);

});
```

In this case, the `resourceTimeout` feature will work as advertised and protect against over-long load times and any page that uses similar animation techniques will work fine.

Comment: Did you test this script with "https://waffles.ch"? It's not working for me. If I use the console with `phantomjs script.js https://waffles.ch` it still hangs up. Phantomj.exe does not close even after closing the console/webpage and the memory usage keeps going up and up. I think it gets jammed on `page.open`, so doesn't read the code it contains..

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean, the load callback is not the place to do it. I can set a timeout from the [onLoadStarted](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-load-started.html) callback but it has the same problem as the resourceTimeout: it feels buggy. If you set a time of up to about 1.6 seconds it will work fine, but anything over that and it looses interest.

Comment: @turrican_34, I figured out the root cause and updated my answer.

Comment: It's working!! I can't thank you enough Cool Blue. I'd all but given up hope of getting a fix for this.What do you mean by "or st better"? Thanks again I'll mark this as the accepted answer. :)

Comment: @turrican_34 yes, it was very satisfying to finally see that screen shot :) by 'st better' I mean that I'm not claiming my shim is perfect ;)  The other thing you could consider is managing the phantomjs process from javascript using [phantomjs-node](https://github.com/amir20/phantomjs-node), maybe you can kill the process if it gets blocked...

Comment: Yes, as a backup, in case phantom hangs or doesn't exit for whatever reason I was going to monitor the phantomJs processes with a system monitor daemon (Linux server) and kill it after x amount of time. I'll work out how to do that when I get there lol.

Comment: Edit: Thanks for the link. This is another option for me to possibly use instead of the system monitor daemon.